# String Concatenate and Hashing Difference between Ruby and PHP

Tags: php, ruby

I'm trying to concatenate two strings and then hashing them with the same method with both PHP and Ruby. The problem is, even if the concatenation steps are exactly same and actually very basic, the returning hashes are different.

**Ruby code:**

```
require 'digest/sha1'
require 'base64'

@user = "0001"
@password = "12345678"

sum_plain = @user + @password
sum_decoded = Digest::SHA1.base64digest(sum_plain)

puts sum_decoded
```

Returns *jwClCsmw2abj6U+YfDNFN+CXmvk=*

**PHP Code:**

```
$user = "0001";
$password = "12345678";
$hashStr = $user + $password;

$sum = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($hashStr)));

echo $sum;
```

Returns *xLk1mbYbhbHxCQZClMW9et9zymY=*

How can it be possible? What am I missing here?

Comment: PHP concatenate is done as $hashStr = $user.$password; + will do the addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So close! The concatenation operator in PHP is a period. You just need:

```
$hashStr = $user . $password;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php for how to concatenate strings in PHP.

> the concatenation operator ('.'), which returns the concatenation of
>   its right and left arguments.

So you want:

```
$hashStr = $user.$password;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP is loosely typed, check this out:
`var_dump(is_int($hashStr));`

PHP changed the type to `int` even tho you had 2 strings. You better be checking the types in the future - that's a must-have. Also concatenation: `$hashStr = $user.$password;`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use `.` to concat strings in PHP.

Seconds you compare different methods. `base64_encode` encodes data with MIME base64. This is an algorithm that can be decoded again with `base64_decode`. That string is used in mails or URLs for example.  Whereas the Ruby method `Digest::SHA1.base64digest` creates a secure hash of the string. The secure hash cannot be decoded. I would not expect the hashes to be the same.